# Java Embeded Closeable Resource in Try - With Statement

Tags: java, reader, writer, try-with-resources, autocloseable

Here's a simple code.

```
try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(new File("c:\\hello.txt"))));)
        {
            writer.write("Hello");
            writer.flush();
        }
```

So basically `FileOutputStream`, `OutputStreamWriter`, and `BufferedWriter` are all closeable resources. However they are not explicitly declared as individual variables in the `try-with` statement. In this case, will Java automatically close all of them after execution or just `BufferedWriter` object?

Comment: See the Javadoc. Every stream that wraps another stream closes it when it is closed itself.

Comment: @user207421 Do you have a link to these javadocs? Because I could not find this feature mentioned, and a quick look at the source for BufferedWriter does not show a close() to the wrapped stream.

Comment: @MTilsted Interesting.  I think this behavior is “common knowledge” which should have been documented, but never was.  The reason it’s common knowledge is that the behavior is, in fact, documented in the [close method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/io/FilterOutputStream.html#close()) inherited by BufferedOutputStream, and I suppose it was understood that BufferedWriter behaves exactly like BufferedOutputStream, but processes characters instead of bytes.  Still, it should have been explicitly documented.

Comment: @VGR @user207421 In the Javadoc, it gives example of an explicit declaration of variables within the `try-with-resource` statement. It is why I made this post, because there's no example of implicit usage of resource within `try-with-resource` statement. Just like @MTilsted has mentioned, the source code for `BufferedWriter` does not invoke `close()` method of the underlying `OutputStreamWriter` object. How can you say it's common knowledge when it's not?

Comment: @VGR is correct. It should be documented in [OutputStreamWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html#close--) as it is for [FilterOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/io/FilterOutputStream.html#close()), and it isn't. But it certainly is common knowledge: just look at almost any Java code: you don't see it closing all the readers and writers and streams, just the outermost ones; whether with or without try-with-resources. You'll see a lot of answers and comments here about that on code with redundant closes.

Comment: @user3009097 Actually, BufferedWriter does close it, but the closure is not obvious because it is not done with an explicit call to `close()`.  It is done at [line 267](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk17/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/io/BufferedWriter.java#L267) in the Java 17 source:  `try (Writer w = out)` is itself a try-with-resources statement that will close `out`, the underlying writer.

Answer (score -1):

The Java will close `BufferedWriter`, which means that it will close every stream it wraps. You could've written your code differently, like so:

```java
try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("c:\\hello.txt"));
OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fos);
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(osw)) {
    writer.write("Hello");
    writer.flush();
}
```

This will not change the way the *try-with-resources* statement works, but it might be easier to read and understand how closing works.

Here is another way of writing the above code that might help illustrate stream closing (this example is for illustration purposes only).

```java
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("c:\\hello.txt"));
try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fos))) {
    writer.write("Hello");
    writer.flush();
}
```

In Java, if any class is closed, then they will also close the underlying streams. In the above example, `BufferedWriter` class is wrapped around `OutputStreamWriter` which wraps around `FileOutputStream` class. As you can see, the instance `fos` is never closed explicitly, but it has been closed because the `BufferedWriter` has been closed by the *try-with-resources* statement.

---

From [java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html):

The `try`-with-resources statement is a`try` statement that declares one or more resources. A resource is an object that must be closed after the program is finished with it. The `try`-with-resources statement ensures that each resource is closed at the end of the statement. Any object that implements `java.lang.AutoCloseable`, which includes all objects which implement `java.io.Closeable`, can be used as a resource.

The following example reads the first line from a file. It uses an instance of `FileReader` and `BufferedReader` to read data from the file. `FileReader` and `BufferedReader` are resources that must be closed after the program is finished with it:

```java
    static String readFirstLineFromFile(String path) throws IOException {
        try (FileReader fr = new FileReader(path);
             BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr)) {
            return br.readLine();
        }
    }
```

In this example, the resources declared in the `try`-with-resources statement are a `FileReader` and a `BufferedReader`. The declaration statements of these resources appear within parentheses immediately after the `try` keyword. The classes `FileReader` and `BufferedReader`, in Java SE 7 and later, implement the interface `java.lang.AutoCloseable`. Because the `FileReader` and `BufferedReader` instances are declared in a `try`-with-resource statement, they will be closed regardless of whether the `try` statement completes normally or abruptly (as a result of the method `BufferedReader.readLine` throwing an `IOException`).

Comment: Are you sure about the closing depending streams thing? Because the javadoc for BufferedWriter does not mention this, and a quick look at the sourcecode for BufferedWriter does not show any call to close.

Comment: @Aleksa Majkic thanks for the explanation. However in the Javadoc, it gives example of an explicit declaration of variables within the `try-with-resource` statement. It is why I made this post, because there's no example of implicit usage of resource within `try-with-resource` statement. Just like @MTilsted has mentioned, the source code for `BufferedWriter` does not invoke `close()` method of the underlying `OutputStreamWriter` object.